# kotlin: can I use qualified return from a closure?

Tags: kotlin, closures, elvis-operator

I want to log&return on null values from a supplier.

Without logging this works fine:

```
    fun check_plain(supplier: Supplier<String?>) {
        val arg: String = supplier.get() ?: return
        // do checking
    }
```

However if I also log behind elvis, I get an error:

```
    fun check_log(supplier: Supplier<String?>) {
        val arg: String = supplier.get() ?: {
            logger.info { "Nothing interesting here" }
            return@check_log // 'return' is not allowed here
        }
        // do checking
    }
```

I work around it, but it's not equivalent, I loose the formal non-nullability:

```
    fun check_if(supplier: Supplier<String?>) {
        val arg: String? = supplier.get().also {
            if (it == null) {
                logger.info { "Nothing interesting here" }
                return@check_if
            }
        }
        // do checking
    }
```

Can I keep the Elvis somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` is not allowed there because the lambda is not inlined. For more info, see [the language spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#return-expressions).

For this simple case, you can just do:

```
val arg: String = supplier.get() ?: return logger.info { "Nothing interesting here" }
```

If you have more statements you want to run, use `run`:

```
val arg: String = supplier.get() ?: return run {
    logger.info { ... }
    logger.info { ... }
    logger.info { ... }
}
```

or:

```
val arg: String = supplier.get() ?: run {
    logger.info { ... }
    logger.info { ... }
    logger.info { ... }
    return
}
```

Note that `return` *is* allowed inside `run` because `run` is inlined.